# A very strange problem that winit block the output from other threads

Tags: macos, rust, event-loop

Currently, I use rust winit on macOS, but I found that sometimes it may block all threads for a few seconds without any output. In order to reproduce the problem, I provide a demo code here:

```
use winit::{
    event::{Event, WindowEvent},
    event_loop::{ControlFlow, EventLoop},
    window::WindowBuilder,
};
use std::process;
use std::time::SystemTime;
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);
    let _ = std::thread::Builder::new()
    .name(format!("global-timer"))
    .spawn(move ||  {
        loop {
            match SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH) {
                Ok(n) => println!("1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC was {} seconds ago!", n.as_secs()),
                Err(_) => panic!("SystemTime before UNIX EPOCH!"),
            }
          std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
        }
    });
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("A fantastic window!")
        .with_transparent(true)
        .with_visible(false)
        .build(&event_loop)
        .unwrap();

    event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow| {
        *control_flow = ControlFlow::Wait;
        // println!("{:?}", event);
        match event {
            Event::WindowEvent {
                event: WindowEvent::CloseRequested,
                window_id,
            } if window_id == window.id() => *control_flow = ControlFlow::Exit,
            Event::MainEventsCleared => {
                window.request_redraw();
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    });
}
```

In this code, there is a line that prints time `Ok (n) => println! ("1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC was {} seconds ago!", N.as_secs ())`. I expected one time per second. In fact, it works as expected when it starts, but after a period of time, it will output after a few seconds or even longer:

[image]

And then I tried windows10 and did not find that problem.

If I change eventloop to basic loop, the problem is not reproduced

How can I make it output every one second without blocked?

my winit version: `winit = "0.20.0"` or winit = "0.21.1"

Thank you~

Comment: You're referring to the looping thread? Then this has nothing to do with `winit`?

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce this without using `winit` by any chance?

Comment: Never mind - I can reproduce this.

Comment: @chub500 yeap, It doesn't seem to matter, but it does be blocked(or some other reasons)

Comment: In Unix systems std::thread::sleep is implemented with nanosleep

Comment: @chub500 emm i still don't understand where the problem is 

Comment: In fact, feature/await is used in my project, but it will still be blocked

Comment: I believe you're running into https://www.lifewire.com/control-how-mac-applications-use-app-nap-2260788 - not sure what the best fix is in rust.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may be able to simply bring the window into focus and the timer will work consistently.